# Conditional expectation of discrete variables

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation, bayes

I am trying to find E[Y|X] when only given the facts that: 
 
    ${\bf P[Y=y] = 2/3, y=0 }$ 
 ${\bf 1/3, y=1 }$ 
 ${\bf 0,   else }$ 
    and ${\bf P[X=x|Y=y] = 2/3, x,y=0}$ or ${\bf x,y=1 }$ 
    ${\bf 1/3, x,y=1,0}$ or ${\bf x,y=0,1}$ 
    ${\bf 0, else}$

 I am trying to solve this using Bayes theorem so that:
    ${\bf f_{y|x}(y|x) = P[X=x|Y=y]\cdot P[X]/P[Y]}$ 
Is this the correct way to go about solving the problem?

Comment: You should double-check the correctness of the formula in your last line.

Comment: Consider solving this from first principles: given this information, you can easily construct the full bivariate distribution $\Pr(X,Y)$--it involves only four outcomes--and from that you can compute anything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 x   y   Pr(Y=y)  Pr(X=x|Y=y)  Pr(X=x, Y=y)  Pr(X=x)      Pr(Y=y|X=x)

 0   0    2/3        2/3             4/9       5/9    (4/9)/(5/9) = 4/5  
 0   1    1/3        1/3             1/9       5/9    (1/9)/(5/9) = 1/5 
 1   0    2/3        1/3             2/9       4/9    (2/9)/(4/9) = 1/2
 1   1    1/3        2/3             2/9       4/9    (2/9)/(4/9) = 1/2
```

Your final line should be something like $$\Pr(Y=y|X=x)=\frac{\Pr(X=x|Y=y)\cdot \Pr(Y=y)}{\Pr(X=x)} $$ $$=\frac{\Pr(X=x|Y=y)\cdot \Pr(Y=y)}{\sum_z \Pr(X=x|Y=z)\cdot \Pr(Y=z)}.$$

From the table, it is rather obvious that $E[Y|X=0]=\frac15$ and $E[Y|X=1]=\frac12$.

Comment: Or, $EY\mid X]$ is a discrete **random variable** taking on values $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ with probabilities $\frac{5}{9}$ and $\frac{4}{9}$ respectively with a cross-check that $$E[E[Y\mid X]] = \frac{5}{9}\times\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{9}\times\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3} = E[Y]$$ as it should be.